# JavaMail - java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Tags: gmail, jakarta-mail, server

This is my code. And though it should be simple enough to send a mail, but I have been encountering the error mentioned below. And I have tried searching everywhere, but with no results.
Thanks in advance !

```
import java.util.Properties;  
import javax.mail.*;  
import javax.mail.internet.*;  

public class SendMailBySite {  
 public static void main(String[] args) {  

 String to="abc@gmail.com";//change accordingly  

  //Get the session object  
  Properties props = new Properties();  
  props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");  
  props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");  
  props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",  
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");  
  props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");  
  props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
  props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");  

  Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,  
   new javax.mail.Authenticator() {  
   protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
   return new PasswordAuthentication("abc@gmail.com","********");//change accordingly  
   }  
  });  

  //compose message  
  try {  
   MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);  
   message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("abc@gmail.com"));//change accordingly  
   message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));  
   message.setSubject("Hello");  
   message.setText("Testing.......");  

   //send message  
   Transport.send(message);  

   System.out.println("message sent successfully");  

  } catch (MessagingException e) {throw new RuntimeException(e);}  

 }  
}
```

**This is the error encountered :**

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
>
> at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
>
> at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
>
> at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
>
> at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
>
> at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
>
> at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
>
> at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>
> at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
>
> at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:182)
>
> at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:203)
>
> at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:296)
>
> at ftpserver.FTPServer.main(FTPServer.java:25)

Answer (score 3):

First, fix all these [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Then read these [debugging tips for connection problems](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).

And you might want to read these [tips for connecting to Gmail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail).

Comment: The common mistakes fixed my issues. There's example code for setting the properties up all over the place and most of it's now obsolete.

Comment: Yup, our mistakes never go away...  :-)

Comment: For me, common mistakes did fix the first problem and the next one (that I was facing) was fixed with the help of [this Google Conversation](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.java.help/c/UJisrJAE64s/m/mUH00rRrTFMJ). Thanks a lot.