# Why not working JavaMail API - Checking Emails?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I developed the Checking Emails system with JavaMail.This is the code I created,

```
  String host = "pop.gmail.com";
  String mailStoreType = "pop3";
  String username = "yourmail@gmail.com";
  String password = "*****";

      Properties properties = new Properties();
      properties.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
      properties.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");
      properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");
      Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
  
      Store store = emailSession.getStore("pop3s");
      System.out.println("2 create store..."+store.toString());

      store.connect(host, user, password);
      System.out.println("3 connected store..."+store);
```

But the code is getting a **Connect failed error** below this I mentioned,

```
1 Strting email service...pop.gmail.com
2 create store...pop3s:
javax.mail.MessagingException: Connect failed;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:209)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at com.demo.service.CheckingMails2.check(CheckingMails2.java:31)
```

**What would be the best possible options?**

Comment: You have `String host = "110";` in your code - Are yu sure that is the correct host and you don't want to use `pop.gmail.com` or similar?

Comment: Also, you might want to check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26952713/10871900).

Comment: @dan1stisonstrike i tried with "String host = "pop.gmail.com";" but it getting same connection failed issue...

Comment: Why aren't you using imap?

Comment: @gimhanas "Connection failed", sounds like a proxy or firewall issue

Comment: As I said, please check the suggestions in the linked answer, especially regarding `Session.getDefaultInstance` and also check the connection with `telnet pop.gmail.com 995` (also mentioned in the linked answer).

Comment: @dan1stisonstrike Yes i tried with it.but have fail senario ----https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16l8cAp6iK7gC0mYZbSzbcx-laaRSXNPE?usp=sharing

Comment: How can "110" be the *host*? That should be `"pop.gmail.com"`

Comment: You're still not posting the correct code. What is creating that output? Nothing in the code I can see could possibly do that

Comment: yes i tried with (pop.gmail.com) but javax.mail.MessagingException: Connect failed; I mention error in description

Comment: I attached my java classes to drive..i need to read emails with java...
so i tried with two examples...(drive files - GmailFetch.java and GmailFetch.java.-->(https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16l8cAp6iK7gC0mYZbSzbcx-laaRSXNPE?usp=sharing)
but both are not working.

Comment: What Java version are you using? An ancient version with outdated TLS support might cause this.

Comment: @JoachimSauer using java 17

Comment: Please post the correct code. That won't even *compile*. When you do post the correct code you probably will eventually run into [this](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833) error (normal passwords won't work)

Answer (score 0):

i'm offering you multiple solutions, first one is to enable all the necessary protocols:

```
properties.put("mail.pop3.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
```

second one is to enable SSL Debugging to see more specific messages, and we will see what is going on:

```
properties.put("mail.debug", "true");
```

last one, you could also bypass the certification process using

> [javax.net.ssl.Trust](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/TrustManager.html)

but i won't advised it will make everything less secure

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at [this](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833) for the password. The following works fine:

```
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Pop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String host = "pop.gmail.com";
            String mailStoreType = "pop3";
            String username = "youraddress@gmail.com";
            String password = "application-specific-password";

            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
            properties.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");
            properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");
            Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

            Store store = emailSession.getStore("pop3s");
            System.out.println("2 create store..." + store.toString());

            store.connect(host, username, password);
            System.out.println("3 connected store..." + store);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```